# Is a Haskell type constructor 'just' a function?

Tags: function, haskell, types, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I am going through *"Haskell Programming from first principles"* and found an exercise asking if the following [code slightly edited here] was valid:

```
module Test where

type Subject = String
type Verb = String
type Object = String

data Sentence = 
  Sentence Subject Verb Object
  deriving (Eq, Show)

a1 = Sentence "I" "like" "cheese"
a2 = Sentence "I" "scream"
```

My expectation was initially that the code would fail, because in the definition of `a2`, `Sentence` only had two arguments. But found that GHCi was happy to load the module. I did a little experimentation and found that I could now type

```
a3 = a2 "icecream"
```

and **`a3`** (typed into GHCi) would print **`Sentence "I" "scream" "icecream"`**. Also, if I inquire the types of **`a2`** I get **`a2 :: Object -> Sentence`**. So if I understand correctly, `a2` is behaving exactly like a partially-applied function.

Question therefore is: Is a type constructor really just a function (that returns a type value) in all situations - distinguished from a 'normal' function only in that it has to start with an upper-case character?

Comment: one part of (the construction part) *is* yes - but you can use those also for pattern-matching and there of course it is not a function any more ;)

Comment: It is a function in the sense you describe yes. You can further confirm this by e.g. typing `:t Just` in ghci.

Comment: @Carsten I haven't done a lot with pattern-matching yet, but as far as I can see, one can us pattern matching both when defining a function (so to do with functions) and when defining a class instance (so to do with types). Can you explain further or give me a reference for how they differ re pattern-matching? Thanks

Comment: @michid So is there any sense in which it is *not* a function, or can I do anything to a type constructor that I can do to a function?

Comment: well if you do `case mySentence of (Sentence s v o) -> ...` for example - here `Sentence` is used for pattern-matching and you cannot insert a function there (well there are extensions ... but on a basic level you cannot)

Comment: yes, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Penguino, pattern matching as discussed in other comments: you cannot use "normal" functions in pattern matching but you can use type constructors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, what you're talking about here are ***data** constructors*, not type constructors. The example happens to contain both a (nullary) type constructor `Sentence` and a ternary data constructor `Sentence`. To make it clear which is which:

```
data SentenceTC = SentenceDC Subject Verb Object
```

`SentenceTC` is a type constructor, `SentenceDC` is a data constructor.

So, the question is:

> Is `SentenceDC` just a function?

and the answer is, it *is* a function, but not “just” a function. It is specifically an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), i.e. every combination of arguments leads to a different result. Because of that, it is always possible to infer which arguments it was, from the resulting `SentenceTC` value. And that's what happens when you *pattern match* on a constructor.

```
a1Verb :: Verb
a1Verb = case a1 of
    Sentence _ v _ -> v
```

This would not be possible with a general function, like

```
n' :: Int
n' = abs n
 where n = -3

nNew :: Int
nNew = case n' of
   abs n -> n   -- error, `abs` can not be used as a pattern match
```

And that wouldn't make sense either, because there are actually two different numbers whose `abs` is equal to `n'` (namely, `-3` and `3`).

But yeah, `SentenceDC` is a function, you can do everything with it that you could do with other functions of type `String -> String -> String -> SentenceTC`. Not the other way around though: not everything you can do with a data constructor can also be done with a general function of the same type.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying being an injective function is not the sole reason you can pattern match. Perhaps a data constructor is a function that can *create* a value, rather than just *returning* a value?

Comment: @chepner, I think it's best to think of a constructor as at least two separate things: a function for constructing values and a pattern for matching on them. Which you get is determined syntactically by where it appears.

Comment: It's also surjective in the sense that every value of type `SentenceTC` is returned by `SentenceDC` for some arguments.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov in this case yes (ignoring ⊥, of course), but that's because there is only one constructor in the example. In general, constructors are not surjective.